# How can I tell docker to create a container from a local image, without looking at the docker hub if no local image is found with that name?

Tags: docker, security, dockerfile, docker-registry

I'm trying to get around what I see as a security issue. If I am working on a project I call "example", I may build a docker image from it using `docker build -t example .`, then run it using `docker run example`. This will work properly, but if I forget to build first, or if I `docker rmi` the image without rebuilding, then docker will query docker hub, and run that image instead.

I trust docker hub for images that I'm already aware of (I'm happy to run `docker run nginx` or `docker run postgres`, for example), but I'm worried about accidentally running arbitrary remote images if I forget to build my local docker image.

I know I could name my local images something esoteric so that collisions are unlikely, but that feels like security by obscurity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to name your images something esoteric.

### Use a namespace

Just register a namespace on docker hub, and then use that in your image names.  E.g., I am `larsks` on Docker Hub. Nobody but me can create an image in the `larsks` namespace, so if I name a local image `larsks/example`, I know that's never going to resolve on Docker Hub unless I put it there.

### Use a bogus registry name

Maybe you don't want to register with Docker Hub.

Recall that the fully qualified form of an image name is `registry/namespace/repository:tag`. If you name your local images with a nonexistent registry, Docker won't be able to pull them from anywhere. E.g., if I name something `dne/larsks/example` (`dne` as in "does not exist", but anything works that isn't a valid hostname), Docker will never be able to pull this image.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer, both of your suggestions make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Name your images with a registry or repository you control. In other words, don't run:

```
docker build -t example .
```

Because that gets expanded to a Docker Official Image repo (aka docker.io/library/) that you don't control. But you can create your own user account on Hub, allowing you to:

```
docker build -t ${your_hub_id}/example .
```

So that any image that doesn't exist locally tries to pull from your namespace on Hub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - looks like the perfect solution.